# Why isn't html <object> element responding to mouse events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, mouse

I have an HTML `<object>` element which is used for displaying an SVG image (`type="image/svg+xml"`). **I am trying to disable the right-click menu on this `<object>` element**, but it appears that it doesn't listen for the mouse events.

I have done the same with a `div` and it's working.

**[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/qzzk7hxt/3/)**

Any clue how to handle this via Javascript/jQuery/CSS? Please note that I must use `<object>` for displaying the SVG.

My code:

```
var url = "https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kiwi.svg";

var svg = document.createElement("object");
svg.setAttribute("id", "svg1");
svg.setAttribute("type","image/svg+xml");
svg.setAttribute("data",url);
document.body.appendChild(svg)

//not responding
svg.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Right-click captured!')
});

//working just fine
var div = document.getElementById("div1");

div.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('Right-click captured!')
})
```

Comment: **[`Its working with your code`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qzzk7hxt/4/)**

Comment: When I right-click the bird, I expect to get an alert and I don't expect to get the right-click menu. Is this what you mean? It's not working for me.

Comment: There isn't any bird getting displayed though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As best as I can tell the `<object>` element is not ["interactive content"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Interactive_content) and therefore is not a clickable area. MDN suggests using a `usemap` attribute paired with a `<map>` tag, but I have not been successful in this approach using the JS Fiddle you provided.

Here's what I recommend: create an overlay shaped to your svg object (in this case I'm just stretching a `<div>` across the entire page). Then, capture and disable the `contextmenu` event:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/kiwi.svg"></object>

<div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0;" oncontextmenu="return false;"></div>
```

Comment: `oncontextmenu="return false"` also disables scrolling. Is there a way to disable the context menu but keep the scrolling functionality?